# Any one have experience with Cognos Gantt Chart?

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-11

I can see in Legacy Visualisation in Cognos have a Gantt chart option. I tried to create but it is not working. I have Planned start date and end date and Actual Start date and end date. How can I create a Gantt chart in IBM Cognos Analytics 11.1 R6.

Comment: Have you tried RAVE?
This link may help 
https://www.ironsidegroup.com/2014/05/05/gantt-charts-using-cognos-10-2-1-rave-technology/

Comment: Yes, I have data set with Planned Start date Planned end date and Actual Start date and Actual end date. Do you think I can create Gantt for four dates I wanted to get two bar one from the planned start and end date and second one Actual Start and end date?

Comment: Can you share the JSON you have tried so far?